# Political Advertising Corpus

Tags: corpora, resource-request

Is there a large political advertising corpus available for download? I am working on a project but the Wesleyan and University of Wisconson corpus are off limits to me. I sent a request on official letterhead with 20 dollars but, because I am a student, was denied. I have downloaded transcripts from CNN and the Living Room candidate but need enough data to perform text mining on.